# Problema con estilos de acuerdo a ruta en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy haciendo un catalogo de productos con Laravel 5.8, y en el front tengo dos rutas, una para el catálogo y otra para el producto elegido

```
Route::get('/categorias_premios', 'PagesController@showCategoriasPremios'); 
Route::get('/categorias_premios/{id}', 'PagesController@showPremio');
```

Esos métodos llaman a vistas que están directamente en **/resources/views** y dichas vistas extienden del mismo template.

Lo extraño es que cuando intento acceder a la categorias_premios/1, **carga la página sin estilos**, pero al inspeccionar la página y agregarle **"../"** a la ruta de los estilos, los carga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas utilizando el helper asset para cargar los estilos?

Por defecto, el helper asset apunta a la raiz de la carpeta public. Puedes modificarlo en el archivo .env

Ej:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!! asset('css/estilos.css') !!}">

<img src="{!! asset('images/nombre-imagen.jpg') !!}" alt="Nombre Imagen" title="Nombre Imagen">
```

Adjunto link con la documetación.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Estaba a punto de poner tu respuesta como comentario, pero al parecer al OP le ha servido. Podrías editar la respuesta para hacerla mas relevante? (Explicar un poco cual era el error del OP y como tu respuesta lo solucionaba)

Comment: Victor, agrega más información a la respuesta para que sea de mayor utilidad para toda la comunidad, revisa [answer], saludos.